# How to import data from javascript to html table

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have created a project that when the page opens, it asks the user to accept his location. When the user accepts, a google maps window opens, displaying the user's current location as well as the coordinates:

[image]

I want the coordinates to be displayed in an html table next to the google maps window, something similar or the same as this below:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I am a begginer in javascript and I need help.
Thank you!!!

*I will post my javascript code in case it's needed:*

```js
// SHOW COORDINATES
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
            center: LatLng,
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: LatLng,
            map: map,
            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
} else {
    alert('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
```

Comment: You can add a listener to the map and then access mapsMouseEvent.latLng like it is described in this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-click-latlng#maps_event_click_latlng-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution to get the lat and lng then here is how you can get inside the function you are using

```
   lat = p.coords.latitude;
   lng = p.coords.longitude;
```

Then you can learn how to insert data in DOM something like this

```
document.getElementById('latvalue').innerHTML += lat;
document.getElementById('lngvalue').innerHTML += lng;
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I created a table with HTML and then passed the latitude and longitude to the id of the <td> with the method you suggested!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `table` element and append it to `document.body` :

```js
// SHOW COORDINATES
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        let table = document.createElement("table");
        table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Latitude</th><th>Longitude</th></tr><tr><td>" + p.coords.latitude + "</td><td>" + p.coords.longitude + "</td></tr>";
        document.body.appendChild(table);
    });
} else {
    console.log('Geo Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
}
```